# How to use repeat vector to predict a sequence of output?

Tags: keras

I am trying to define a model that works for a sequence of images and tries to predict a sequence in turn. My problem is with the repeat vector, specifically is it the right use of it and secondly how to resolve the exception that I get.

```
input_frames=Input(shape=(None, 128, 64, 1))
x=ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', return_sequences=True)(input_frames)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', return_sequences=False)(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='sigmoid',padding='same')(x)
x=RepeatVector(10)(x)
model=Model(inputs=input_frames,outputs=x)
```

Specifically, I am trying to forecast 10 frames in future. The above code throws the following exception:

```
assert_input_compatibility
str(K.ndim(x)))
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer repeat_vector_5: expected ndim=2, found ndim=4
```

Answer (score 1):

From [the doc of RepeatVector](https://keras.io/layers/core/#repeatvector), it only accept 2D inputs, that's what the error message is telling you.

Following is a workaround using `Lambda` layer:

```
from keras.layers import Input, ConvLSTM2D, BatchNormalization, RepeatVector, Conv2D
from keras.models import Model
from keras.backend import expand_dims, repeat_elements
from keras.layers import Lambda

input_frames=Input(shape=(None, 128, 64, 1))
x=ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', return_sequences=True)(input_frames)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=ConvLSTM2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(5, 5), padding='same', return_sequences=False)(x)
x=BatchNormalization()(x)
x=Conv2D(filters=1, kernel_size=(5, 5), activation='sigmoid',padding='same')(x)
#x=RepeatVector(10)(x)
x=Lambda(lambda x: repeat_elements(expand_dims(x, axis=1), 10, 1))(x)
model=Model(inputs=input_frames,outputs=x)
model.summary()

"""
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
input_15 (InputLayer)        (None, None, 128, 64, 1)  0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_5 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, None, 128, 64, 64) 416256    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, None, 128, 64, 64) 256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv_lst_m2d_6 (ConvLSTM2D)  (None, 128, 64, 64)       819456    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_6 (Batch (None, 128, 64, 64)       256       
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 128, 64, 1)        1601      
_________________________________________________________________
lambda_1 (Lambda)            (None, 10, 128, 64, 1)    0         
=================================================================
Total params: 1,237,825
Trainable params: 1,237,569
Non-trainable params: 256
_________________________________________________________________
"""
```

Note that I use a `expand_dims` here since from [the doc of repeat_elements](https://keras.io/backend/#repeat_elements), it won't create new axis.